# How to use subtitles filter to a video VFR ( variable frame rate ) video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have created a VFR (variable frame rate) video from a list of images by using the following `ffmpeg` command.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

where the `concat.txt` is a text file which contains the list of the image locations and durations in the below format.

```
file image01.png
duration 3
file image02.png
duration 5
file image02.png
```

I have a subtitle file (`.srt` file) that I would like to add to the generated video by using the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1) filter.

I tried to use the `subtitles` filter by running the following command

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -codec:a copy -vf subtitles=subtitles.srt -max_muxing_queue_size 4096 outputWithSubtitles.mp4
```

I find that the resultant output file does not show any subtitles.

I find that if instead of VFR video if constant frame rate video is generated, then this issue is not observed i.e., during the generation of the first video from images if `-vsync vfr` option is not used, then a constant frame rate video is generated and using subtitles filter works.

Is there a way to use the subtitles filter on a VFR video?

Comment: Possible, but tedious. With VFR input, there may not exist any frames to draw upon during the time interval of a subtitle entry. You can try to ensure there are, by adding duplicate entries to your concat text, with duration values modified to ensure that frames exist during those times, with one duplicate entry for when the subtitle disappears.

Comment: Do note that your subtitle command, even if worked, would generate a CFR output. You need to carry over the `-vsync vfr` option.